# Spreadsheet triggers not fired from form add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a private editor add-on for Google forms, similar to the existing "Form Approvals" add-on on the marketplace. The add-on is bound to a form document and during onboarding (called from the onOpen menu on initial start), I install three triggers; (1) form submit for the current form, (2) form submit for the spreadsheet where the form responses are saved and (3) onEdit for the same spreadsheet.

When I run the script in development (not as an add-on from the marketplace), everything works fine. When I run the script as an add-on (private to my organization, installed from the marketplace), the trigger for the form is fired without issues, but neither of the two spreadsheet triggers are fired. Is this a limitation or an issue?

Code snippet from my onboarding function (only called when the add-on is opened for the first time):

```
  createResponseSpreadsheet(); /* assures that a response spreadsheet exists */
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId()); /* is not null */
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('spreadsheetOnFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet).onFormSubmit().create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('spreadsheetOnEdit').forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet).onEdit().create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('formOnFormSubmit').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
```

And the trigger functions:

```
function spreadsheetOnEdit(e) {
  /* ... */
}

function spreadsheetOnFormSubmit(e) {
  /* ... */
}

function formOnFormSubmit(e) {
  /* ... */
}
```

OAuth scopes for the project:

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://mail.google.com/"
  ],
```

Some extra information:

- The spreadsheet is assured to exist by the time the triggers are installed.
- I can look at the triggers in the apps script project - they exist, point to the correct document and the right function.
- The triggered function for the form is executed. The triggered function for the spreadsheet is never executed.

I have tried:

- Deleting the triggers and re-installing them (programmatically)
- Deleting the triggers, creating a new version for the add-on, then re-installing them (programmatically)

Comment: 1. try `.forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet.getId()).` 2. Is the trigger created? `trigger.getId()`?

Comment: The onEdit trigger will not run on form submit. onEdit will run only on an edit event from a keyboard. I am not sure about the other trigger

Comment: Thank you! Turns out it is not possible to create spreadsheet triggers from an add-on that is bound to a form document. More specifically, one cannot fire triggers from documents other than the document where the add-on was installed. Got this response from the google issue tracker, referring me to the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers).